# PPS / Performance Point Date Range for Scorecards

Tags: ssas, performancepoint, date-range, daterangepicker

How do I go about adding a From and To date range to a scorecard and analytic report?

It doesn't seem to be well documented anywhere (including PPS books!) but surely a basic requirement for any report.

Is it possible? Or is it necessary to add 2 filters: a DateTime picker and a 'Lag' filter (which contains the number of days / weeks / months in a dropdown):

The requirement is to create a scorecard, with KPIs based on previous years performance, so there are 2 date parameters both of which need to be passed into the KPI to filter down the results (ParallelPeriod).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with analytical reports, but not with the scorecard. For the report I wouldn't necessarily recommend it because you will need to modify the MDX to setup parameters and that means you will lose the interactivity features with the report.  Here is an example of setting up parameters in the MDX - http://dailyitsolutions.blogspot.com/2011/01/from-date-to-date-in-performancepoint.html.

Dashboarding is typically looking at and anlyzing periods of times which you can easily do versus the date ranges that you would typically find in operational reporting.  You might want to take a look at possibly using some time intelligence features that are available in PerformancePoint if you do not have this available in your SSAS database.

Here is an overview on the TI formulas - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2010/01/21/time-intelligence-formula-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: great thanks, noticed the interactivity loss yesterday - a bit frustrating but understandable given the custom MDX is simply parsed.

Also need the use of scorecards, mainly for KPIs and managed to get a simple DateTimePicker and TI filter filter to work in conjuction with each other to give stats for a specified date (DTP) and Lag (TI formula filter), seems to work as expected.   Thanks again